# Inconsistent behavior for login with Customer Portal and Sites

Tags: force.com-sites, customer-portal, authentication

We tried to implement the Customer Portal and Sites together, but we encountered a problem when we deployed to production (works fine in sandbox).

This is the behavior we're seeing:

- Users log in with a customized login page that we built.
- After they login, they should be taken to a Change Password page (we're using the standard ChangePassword page).  Instead, the standard Salesforce login page is displayed.  Oddly, the URL seems to be the correct URL for the ChangePassword page: 
  `<SITE_URL>/_ui/system/security/ChangePassword?retURL=<RET_URL>&fromFrontdoor=1&display=page&setupid=ChangePassword`
- After logging in a second time, they go back to the same URL, and this time it displays the Change Password page.  However, there are three fields displayed (Old Password, New Password, and Verify New Password), but since it is a new user, the old password should not be displayed.

The weird thing is that it is inconsistent across different browsers and machines -- and sometimes it just goes away, then it comes back. Do you have any idea on what the problem is? million thanks!

Comment: I had trouble understanding the question so tried reformatting it a bit for clarity - can you double-check that the problem/question is still being laid out correctly?

Comment: Thank you Benj -- yes that is correct. i'm a little bit new to stackexchange. :)

Comment: Have you modified the SiteLoginController class? If so can you post that controller's code?

Answer (score 1):

We had a built a custom change password page for our force.com site. To avoid the verify password text, check the default change password page. you would notice a snippet of code in it which checks for user login. Put that snippet in your custom visual force page and make sure you have updated the change password page on the force.com site settings. Let me know if this works?

Answer (score 0):

We did a separate controller for sites visitors to both register and to change their passwords. The issue is that they're a "contact" and not a "user" in the context of SF. Perhaps that may the issue you're contending with as well? That also applies to your portal visitors too if it's for accounts/customers and not for your users.